# Flash Builder as AS3 Editor for Flash IDE Question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I have been using Flash Builder 4.5.1 as as Editor for my Flash IDE projects. This works great, mostly. I love that I can compile into the Flash IDE from Flash Builder. However, it is very annoying that every time I save anything in a class file, Flash Builder publishes the project in Flash. This is ok when the project is small, but as it starts to grow it really gets in the way. Is there a way to turn this "feature" off?

Thanks!

Comment: *cough* download flashdevelop http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page *cough* :D

Comment: I have to agree, FlashDevelop is a better development platform (if you know what you're doing), or at least it was when FlexBuilder 3 was the latest version. Things might be better now, but I still can't get over the hugely elephantine feel of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I work on Macs.

Comment: Let me elaborate on my previous comment... For years I used Eclipse/FDT, which really is a great combination, but the price of both FDT and CS5 starts to be unjustifiable when FB is in the package. This is why I am switching to FB. I like the IDE integration and I love the Eclipse platform. Since I know what I am doing in and beyond Flash and ActionScript, it is convenient to have easy access to Ant, SVN, GIT, Aptana, PHP, etc, etc, etc. FlashDevelop, like Eclipse, is built on Java, which is why I don't understand why it has to be platform-specific. If it was, I would consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [this blog entry](http://www.albertx.mx/blog/flash-builder-projects/) mentions that you can turn it off by unchecking Build Automatically.

An excerpt:

> Removing the Build Automatically
>   option in Flash Builder: First open
>   Adobe Flash Builder and before create
>   any project or anything just remove
>   the Build Automatically option located
>   under Project -> Build Automatically.
>   This will avoid Flash Builder to
>   compile the code every time you save a
>   file.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find in the preferences.